# Is there a way to bypass POS Credit Card processing fees?

Tags: credit-card, fees, debit-card, transaction

**Summary:** If you have a shop and you accept Credit/Debit cards like *Visa, Mastercard, Maestro, American Express, etc.,* you have to pay a fee. Is there any way to keep accepting those cards without paying the fees?

---

I went to the shop and I bought an item which cost $1.20. I asked the seller and he confirmed that he has to pay $0.70 for that transaction. The seller also added that he bought the item for $0.60. This means he lost $0.10. He confirmed there is no way to avoid this. I'm not sure if this applies to online transactions as well.

**Why should the fees be paid?** I believe there are also good reasons to keep paying those fees:

- Credit Card circuit provides fast transaction execution compared to... (is there any comparison alternative, maybe online payment alternative)?
- Credit Card circuit checks during the transaction if the card is valid and has not been stolen.
- ...
- ...any other reason?

Comment: The fee is the price the merchant pays to have the credit card company process the transaction and send the merchant money. How would they get out of paying it?

Comment: I suppose that OP is asking, what’s up with having to have brokers? why is it that merchants find it impossible to deal with credit card companies directly. Not unlike, why must we go via car dealerships when purchasing a car, but can’t buy directly from its manufacturer. It’s not the service fee that’s in question, but the unnecessary—but mandatory—merchant service provision itself.

Comment: Your seller is getting hosed. Stripe's fees are $0.30 + 2.9% (33 cents in your example), and they're on the high end. https://stripe.com/pricing

Comment: Fees can vary a lot between countries, networks, card types (debit v credit but also personal v business), national/international, the merchant’s bank, their contract… some contracts smooth everything out and have a single fee structure for all cards, others are much more complex. Many acquirers (banks for merchants) have special contracts for small amounts (due to the introduction of contactless and the small transactions it draws). They should just shop around.

Comment: Can you clarify which country this is, whether the card was debit or credit, which network, contact or contactless?

Comment: "Why should the fees be paid?" -- why did you give the store $1.20? Because you wanted the item they were willing to sell to you for that price. This is no different.

Comment: @ceejayoz pretty sure the seller is lying to op to make them feel bad and buy something else.

Comment: @ceejayoz German girocard has 0.18% transaction fee.  2.9% is a terrible rip-off.

Comment: @gerrit Maestro (at least in NL) has around 6 cents flat fee, but for MasterCard/VISA it jumps up to 1.7%. These fees are simply all over the place internationally, depending on the relative power of the payment providers.

Comment: @gerrit That's the US system. High interchange rates, high cashback rewards. I get 2-5% back on every transaction from my card, but it factors into pricing.

Comment: @gerrit Is girocard convenient for online transactions?

Comment: If you think this is bad, consider that Apple and Google have fees around 30% for purchases through their app stores, and Apple disallows apps from offering other payment methods (although they lost a lawsuit last year about this).

Comment: @MonkeyZeus By itself girocard doesn't support online transactions (it doesn't support card-not-present transactions at all), but it does via systems such as [*sofortüberweisung*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sofort%C3%BCberweisung), which many German merchants and some international providers (including, crucially, paypal) support, and involves a card authorisation via the customer's online bank.

Comment: The other thing no one has mentioned yet is that the credit card company is basically giving a 30 day interest free loan to the consumer when they buy things. Why would they offer such a service without charging for it?

Comment: @JohnFx that's not exactly true, the merchants are not always immediately paid out. Many times the service provider pays merchants out weekly/biweekly/monthly, thus essentially forcing the merchants to bear some of that costs. It is also what helps with chargebacks.

Comment: @ceejayoz the OP's profile says they're in NZ - bank structures may well be different to where you are and 1 NZD is about 0.65 USD

Comment: @ChrisH Interchange rates outside the US are typically dramatically lower, and that appears to include NZ: https://www.kiwibank.co.nz/personal-banking/credit-cards/rates-and-fees/interchange-fees/

Comment: $0.70 per transaction ?! That's such a rip-off. All they do is transferring the money.

Comment: Apple Pay charges something like 0.07% in China (competitive with other options which are 0% to 0.1%), and reportedly about double than in the US.

Comment: The way to avoid fees is to pay in cash. Aside from that, the very question is essentially "can I use service X without paying for it?" which, if put into those terms, should make it obvious how ridiculous the question is.

Comment: Don't I remember, fees for low-value card transactions used to be not-uncommon here in the UK, and have faded away as processing became easier and cheaper?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

> Is there any way to keep accepting those cards without paying the fees?

No. You're receiving a service, why would you be receiving it for free?

> He confirmed there is no way to scape to this.

That's incorrect. He can avoid these fees by not accepting credit cards for such a small charge. Cash is legal tender.

The credit card companies allow (after being sued numerously) merchants to set minimum transaction amounts below which merchants are not required to accept credit cards for payment. This is specifically to avoid cases where the fee is prohibitively high compared to the transaction amount.

The fees are usually structured with either fixed floor or with a fixed component. For example, 2% of the transaction, but no less than $0.50 (fixed floor), or $0.25+2% of the transaction (fixed component). Both make it significantly more expensive to accept credit cards for low amounts.

Comment: Why would merchants need to sue in order to be allowed to reject credit cards for transactions under a minimum amount? Couldn't they just set that as their store policy, kind of like how some stores have policies about unaccompanied minors and how many bad checks get you banned?

Comment: @RobertColumbia Because the card network (e.g. VISA) would have a policy saying they're not allowed to do that, and saying if they violate the policy they will be disconnected from the network. The lawsuit would be to make the network let them do it without being disconnected.

Comment: @RobertColumbia the networks have a lot of power over the merchants. This is de-facto a duopoly (VISA+Mastercard hold all the market, AMEX, Diners Club, Discovery, UnionPay, JCB - are all local and globally insignificant even combined together). There were multiple anti-trust lawsuits against both MC and VIsa, both in the US and the EU, due to various unfair policies including demanding the merchant accept their cards for all transactions or refuse accepting competitors' cards.

Comment: Worth noting also that it's not uncommon for businesses that deal with low-priced items to have a fee that offsets their loss on low-priced transactions. For example finding at the register: "A $0.50 processing fee will be added to any credit card transaction less than $5". It doesn't really avoid the fee which is what OP asked but technically allows the business to offset the loss which is kinda what looks like it spurred the question.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136587/discussion-on-answer-by-littleadv-is-there-a-way-to-bypass-pos-credit-card-proce).

Comment: @McAden In *many* countries adding fees for card transactions is illegal, and in general it is illegal anything that would change the price depending on the payment method (e.g. discount for cash). In some countries merchants cannot refuse to let the clients pay by cards if the amount is above a certain limit (e.g. in Italy the limit is currently 15€), some countries have laws such that some circuits waive fees for transactions below a certain amount (in Italy transactions "Pagobancomat" below 5€ cannot have processing fees attached) or there are caps on the amunt processor can charge.

Comment: @McAden, charging a fee for using a debit or credit card is illegal in Texas: https://statutes.capitol.texas.gov/Docs/BC/htm/BC.604A.htm

Comment: I was not referring to a specific location. It is indeed illegal in some, and legal in others. It is legal in most US States and I've seen it in multiple countries. I'm not giving advice, simply pointing out there are ways some merchants can avoid taking so much of a loss. Any merchant should obviously refer to the law for their area and it can be complicated even in TX - See Rowell v. Paxton (https://www.courtlistener.com/docket/4401158/96/rowell-v-paxton/)

Comment: Either way, the few times I've asked lawyers they've clear that "legal tender" isn't the point. Tender is "legal" only "for the payment of debts". No debt exists in a normal shop transaction, because the contract is immediately fulfilled. 

The item becomes the property of the purchaser at, not before and not after the exact moment the price is paid. Since that is also the moment at which the contract is made, no can exist, so "legal tender" can't count.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin that doesn't work in a sit-down restaurant where you consume the product before you get to the cashier, but still need to pay. As I asked previously - what do you imagine happening if you're in a restaurant and only have cash when the waiter comes with the check? You owe them, don't you?

Comment: @Littleadv Sorry, a restaurant is not a shop. If you want to argue about different categories of retail premises, please either go to Chat or Post a new Question, citing your research.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin I don't, you were the one who's arguing. Cash is in fact legal tender, and it is not uncommon for merchants to purchase goods with delayed payments. Not sure what your argument is.

Comment: @littleadv Sorry. Ask a lawyer. Despite your personal belief, it matters not a jot that cash is legal tender; only where legal tender  applies, ie, to the settlement of debts and not to shopping. Ask your own lawyer.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin I really don't understand what you think your argument is here and why you think you're contradicting something I said.... I think I'll just disengage. Just pointing out two things: *"only where legal tender applies, ie, to **the settlement of debts**"* and "*How could it matter whether it was common for merchants to purchase goods with **delayed payments**?*"

Comment: @Littleadv Sorry you didn't understand and how is that my responsibility? Still, good luck in future, too.

Answer (score 10):

As to why merchants take credit cards, even with fees, the common answer answer is an increase in sales. A friend started taking credit cards and her business double or tripled in volume. As her cheapest item was $6.00 and the average item was $20 - $30, the fees did not kill the profit margin.
The most expensive items were $1200 - $1400.
It was not uncommon for people to buy $250 - $400 of stuff.
For average retail, most people don't walk around with hundreds in cash.

Large volume cash shows tend to be at wholesale shows for vendors. One off transactions for hundreds or thousands of dollars, where you would not trust anything but physical currency (because checks and cards can be forged and the seller often eats those losses). Even then, once a business relationship is formed, things other than cash become allowed.

Today, many buyers expect to be able to pay with a credit card. The only major places than don't are MJ, tiny food vendors, and individuals (me buying something from a friend). Even the government will often take credit cards (but  may upcharge you the 3% transaction fee).

EDIT: Just a note, this is how things work in America. Other countries have different standards and practices. The numbers listed in the original question looked like American Credit Card numbers, so the specific answer was based on that. Note, debit cards may (often do) have different processing fees. Point of the answer to was answer why a merchant would take Credit Cards. In the absence of a cheaper electronic payment system, it is usually good for business.

Comment: This is a very American answer.  In Germany, almost all shops accept girocard, but many do not accept credit cards.  The fees for girocard are about 1/10th compared to the fees for VISA/MasterCard.  Credit card payments are very rare in Germany (I use mine exclusively for rental cars), so the only reason to accept them is for foreign visitors from countries where banks do not interact with girocard.

Comment: @gerrit. Isn’t girocard just a debit card?  The question and this answer seem to me to just use the phrase credit card but really seem to draw a distinction between paying by a card versus paying with hard currency (paper and coins).   In the US debit fees are also lower than credit fees generally, though may still be higher than girocard fees I’m not sure.  And a lot of people here just call everything a credit card.

Comment: I find alot of places use credit card to just mean anything from visa/mastercard, even if you got a debit card from visa/mastercard.

Comment: @Rob In the US, any place that accepts credit cards will naturally accept debit cards as well -- they're processed by the same card networks, and the fees are lower, so there's no reason not to. So there's little reason for them to make the distinction (unless they're cheap and *only* accept debit cards -- I don't think I've seen this anywhere in the US).

Comment: @Barmar This is not in the US, this is in (some) shops in EU countries that don't want to pay the visa/mastercard fees so they say "no credit cards" but they really mean no visa/mastercard cards.

Comment: @Rob actually debit cards don't work on the same networks. Debit card transactions are handled through different networks (some owned by Visa or MC, but not all, and in fact there's much more competition there). They ride essentially the same networks as ATM, and you can see many different network logos on ATM machines in the US, not just Visa or MC or their ATM brands (like cirrus or maestro). Girocard is indeed a similar type of card.

Comment: @quid Girocard is a debit card, but one that's not on the Visa/Mastercard network.  Visa Debit and Mastercard Debit are very unusual in Germany, and in fact my bank started offering them for the first time just a month ago.  Due to them being so unusual, merchants saying "no credit cards" usually mean "no Visa/Mastercard".  I don't know how the fees for Visa Debit / Mastercard Debit compare to credit cards or girocard.

Comment: @gerrit regarding Germany, this used to be true, but seems to be rapidly changing (maybe due to COVID - cashless/touchless transaction becoming preferred?). Last time I was there, I paid with credit card literally everywhere. I saw people pay for a single item at the bakery with a credit card. Nobody even seemed to think twice about it. Many banks are also recently charging monthly fees for debit cards, so credit cards are becoming more and more popular.

Answer (score 7):

> Is there any way to keep accepting those cards without paying the fees?

I think there might be some special rules/discounts if you're operating a [non-profit 501(c)(3)](https://www.501c3.org/what-is-a-501c3/) but that doesn't apply to your scenario.

> He confirmed there is no way to avoid this. I'm not sure if this applies to online transactions as well.

Yes, this applies to online sales as well. Accepting credit card payments means that you're paying for a service. Do you eat a satisfactory dinner at a restaurant and then think of ways to not pay? Of course not, you chose to have this service provided to you.

> WHY SHOULD THE FEES BE PAYED?

Because the merchant chose to accept credit card payments at their business.

---

So, how do you mitigate the pain of credit card payment fees for low-value items as a merchant?

- Raise your base sale price to account for the transaction fee

  - That $1.20 could have costed $2 instead
- Do not accept credit cards below a certain threshold

  - Small shops/restaurants often impose a $20 minimum purchase if paying by credit card
- Offer 2 prices: cash price and credit card price

  - Gas stations have implemented this tactic in my area for many years now; it's usually a $0.10/gallon difference but I suspect they will raise it fairly soon
  - A local restaurant which I frequent tacks on a 3% credit card processing fee if paying with a credit card

---

Most places tend to take the gamble that high-value transactions outweigh the occasional low-value sale. It's called "the cost of doing business".

Gas stations and convenience stores in less affluent neighborhoods might opt to not accept credit card at all if their transactions are usually less than $20.

Comment: The card minimum really depends on the store. I know of many local stores that have either a $5 or $10 minimum rather than $20. It really depends on what they sell and whatever agreements they have with the payment processor.

Comment: Some of mitigations listed may not be available. In the UK, differential pricing is actually illegal.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Can you provide a source? The closest thing I can find is that it's illegal to apply differential pricing based on a protected class like sex, race, religion, etc... I don't believe payment method is a protected class. Some businesses might get around this anyways by listing a single price and offering a discount if paying with cash.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus It's Consumer Protection legislation. See https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/payment-surcharges and Sections 12-13 of the guidance document there.

Comment: @AndrewLeach So 13.3 bullet point #2 tells me that everything I described is legal?

Comment: No: there can't be a surcharge (eg 3% processing fee). There can be a discount for cash. I guess that relates to the "headline price" -- you can't add a surcharge to that, even though you can choose to allow a discount.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Right, so it's all about how the merchant words it. $0.10/gallon discount for cash and the restaurant says 3% discount for cash payments? Ultimately, the surcharge **is** passed along to the consumer.

Answer (score 0):

#### Only for regular customers.

The shop owner might issue his own customer cards. Payment is done via debit charge at the end of the day/week/month. The shop owner will need to have his own infrastructure to collect the payment data for his "premium customers" and will have to offer an incentive for his "premium customers", typically some discount. Note that while cash discounts are illegal in some places, giving a discount to "premium customers" is legal.

Obviously, this won't work for non-regular customers, so the shop owner will have to accept the regular plastic money, but the incentive will convince the "premium customers" to stay with the shop's "premium card".

Note that there debit charge fees as well; they are however usually cheaper than what the credit card companies charge. Plus, it's also possible to charge the customer at the end a month (for the cumulated sum of the individual purchases in that month) to reduce the fees even further - at the cost of having to wait up to a month for the money.

After all, the shop owner will need to calculate whether this could a be a working solution. If there are enough reliable regular customers, this will work.

Answer (score -1):

**Is there a way to bypass POS Credit Card processing fees?**

No: if you want to accept cards for payment you will need to pay a fee for that service.

But there could / should be different providers on the market with different fee structures. Searching might reveal providers with lower price per transaction or lower total cost (depending what else a package of services might include).

I see an unhealthy effect of the fee structure and increased use of cards in chains of shops around where I live - they tend to stop selling goods with a unit price below a certain price level. Not selling single "something", as example, only selling double packs or sixpacks or similar.

Comment: When downvoting, it would help me to make better answers in the future if I could get some kind of explanation.